# Finding the number of fails between 3 sets of array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

This is a simple coding questions that is asking to sum the marks for each students. If the total marks reaches the pass mark then reach to the next student. If they did not reach the pass marks then it will return as failed.

```
class StudentMarks {

public int getCountFailures() {
    int[] student1 = {3, 2, 6, 4, 3, 6, 6, 7, 3, 2};
    int[] student2 = {8, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7, 6, 8, 9, 6};
    int[] student3 = {2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 6};
    int[][] allStudents = {student1, student2, student3};
    int numberFails = 0;
    int passMark = 50;

    // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
   



    return numberFails;
}
```

}

**Test code**

```
    int numberFails = marks.getCountFailures();
    System.out.println("Number of fails = " + numberFails);
```

How would I implement a way to sum the marks for each of the students and return the number of fails.

**The expected outcome**

Number of fails = 2

Comment: Not a place to ask people to do your homework for you. You should try this on your own.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

Seems as a homework question, so this is not a complete answer but would help you come up with one on your own.

```
// will return the count of the arrays - the sum of the elements
// of which are equal to or cross the threshold.
long count = 
    Arrays.stream(allStudents)
        .peek(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)))
        .filter(a -> thresholdSum(a) )
        .count();
    
System.out.print(count);
```

This is the helper method.

```
public static boolean thresholdSum(int[] a) {
    
    int threshold = 50;
    int sum =0;
    for (int i : a) {
        sum += i;
        if (sum >= threshold) {
            return true;
        }
        
    }
    return false;
    
    
}
```